# Playing audio subtitles using html5

Tags: html5-audio

I need some help on displaying subtitles for a mp3 file. While it plays the audio on chrome but it does not display any subtitles. Secondly, once audio starts playing, it does not give an option to pick any controls(except volume).

Here is the snippet of the code. Any help will be appreciated!

```
<audio controls id="sample_audio" width="800" height="600" preload="none">
  <source type="audio/mp3" src="7f1d4d9d-98f8-4e87-baca-4d883dfc37f4.mp3" />
  <track src="./captions_output_1612284679.vtt" kind="subtitles" srclang="en" label="English" >

 </audio>
```

Comment: After debugging, realized CORS is preventing to load the page. Once that is fixed with the following  "chrome.exe --allow-file-access-from-files" ran into another issue.   "Resource interpreted as TextTrack but transferred with MIME type text/plain". so far, everyone used .htaccess file but in my case it is a local file.

Answer (score 0):

This issue mainly related to Chrome preventing access to the local files and preventing the access when there is no https. In my case, do not want to expose the chrome insecure content.

As a solution, leveraged AWS S3 with cloudfront and that resolved the issue.